# EF DB First how to generate model classes in other layer?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

A MVC application has the following layers:

**1. User Interface:**
Web MVC site, it has views and controllers **but not models**

1. Business
   it has Models, ViewModels, Services, Common classes
2. DataAccess
   it has EF DB first and Repositories

User Interface calls Business and Business calls Data Access layers.

**Issue**
Since my EF DB first implementation is in Data Access layer, every time I do changes it generates POCO classes in DataAccess layer. I can manually cut and move generated poco classes to Business layer but want to ask is there a way I may not need to manually cut and move generated class files to Business layer and they may be automatically generated there in destination layer and folder ?

Thanks for your help precious time and guidance.

Comment: How can you be using both EF5 and EF6 at the same time? Choose the one you're using.

Comment: You don't want to use those EF generated classes for any data binding or presentation logic, this is what ViewModels would be for. Those generated classes are part of the data layer and don't belong any where else. Don't cut and paste those classes to your Biz layer, that is bad, very bad. Instead create ViewModels and Map your Biz Layer objects to your data access POCO classes when it comes to CRUD operations